# How to evaluate typed-out formulas in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, formula, units-of-measurement, evaluate

If I type the formula `1/4*pi()*($A$1)^2` as a string in a cell and assuming I have a value in $A$1, I use the following VBA function in a third cell to evaluate the formula:

```
Public Function E(byval TextFormula as String) as Variant
  E = Evaluate(TextFormula)
End Function
```

Is there a way to use math characters like •, √, ¼, π, ², etc. so that my typed-out formula looks more agreeable?  Even translate '[' and ']' as '(' and ')'.  I can just iterate through an array replacements using REPLACE() function for the simple characters but what about the extended characters like π?

For the really sharp macro'ers...

What about showing intermediate steps (iterations) as in `(2*3) + (2.5*4)` evaluates to `6 + 10` in the first iteration and then `16` in the next iteration.  Asside: I would want the iterations to stop just before each set of addings/subtractings because I sometimes like to know what the relative magnitudes of the individual evaluated terms are to see what part of my formula is controlling the result.

And for the mega-genius ones...

What about mixed units?  Such as typing out `560{lbs}/[1.23{m}*3.4{'}]` and getting my result in `###{psf}` as an example.  I thought that the unit could be delineated by the underscore such as `34_kN` but I think a start and end delineation is required for compound units like `34{kN/m^2}`.  There would need to be a way to force the output to a desired unit (ie. mm instead of in) like maybe setting up your desired units ahead in your sheet and then it would at least try to convert to one of those units.  I think at this stage you will be charging me for the code;)

I like using Excel for my engineering calculations because I only use simpler formulas (no calculus!) and I don't want to constantly switch between Excel and Mathcad apps but use only one.

Shawn

Answer (score 0):

Those are tall orders. The following sub might give you an idea for your first question:

```
Sub test()
    Dim R As Range
    Set R = Range("A1")
    R.Value = "A = pr2"
    R.Characters(5, 1).Font.Name = "Symbol"
    R.Characters(7, 1).Font.Superscript = True
End Sub
```

Run it an then look at the contents of A1

As far as your second question goes - sure you can do it, but you would need to write a full-fledged expression parser. Writing one from scratch is fairly involved (at least a couple hundred lines of code) and is probably best done by using classes to create a custom tree data type then writing a recursive descent parser to parse strings into expression trees. Doable, though I have neither the time nor the inclination to do so.

I'm not quite sure what you are driving at with your last question, though my gut reaction is that it is easier than your second question since no real parsing is required and it is easy enough to create a dictionary of conversion factors.

Comment: Hi John and thanks.  I may not be able to go and programmatically alter the characters this way every time I enter a formula.  I was thinking of just insert the symbol from the INSERT -> SYMBOL command on the ribbon, in the actual font I am using (such as Arial or Calibri).  Alternatively I already programmed some of the basic ones and greek into my AUTOCORRECT such as \a gives me α, \* gives me ·, \_| gives me ⊥, \^2 gives me ², \/ gives me √, etc.  Alternatively, alternatively I can just hold Alt and type the character code and get it that way.  Alt-0248 gives me ø.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of programmatically altering each and every formula in the explicit way my sub did it. That was just to illustrate that VBA is able to adjust font on individual characters and thus create strings which display as combinations of ordinary characters and symbols. To make it useful, you would need to create a sort of code where e.g. \p is pi (sort of like what you are already doing with autocorrect) and then have VBA implement the translation scheme. What you already do sounds clever, but a VBA approach might be more flexible.